# SPARQL Query, select only if ALL the objects of one subject matches with objects of another subject

Tags: sparql, ontology, knowledge-graph

Suppose I have a situation where I want only those shops that repair all the problems that my car has. The example knowledge graph is given in the below image.

[Example Image of the Knowledge Graph with instances as explained above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVKEU.png)

**In the present example: These are the following triples**

```
<.car> <.hasRepair> <.engine>  
<.car> <.hasRepair> <.color>  
<.car> <.hasRepair> <.body>  
 
<.shop1> <.doesService> <.color>  
<.shop2> <.doesService> <.engine>  
<.shop2> <.doesService> <.color>  
<.shop2> <.doesService> <.body>
```

I want a SPARQL query that will select only shop2 as it matches all the repairs of car, whereas shop1 does not solve all the repairs.

Also, shop2 can have other services for which the car does not need any repair (like oil change)

Comment: double negation via `FILTER NOT EXISTS` is the way to go. `select ?s where {?s a :Shop . filter not exists {<.car> <.hasRepair> ?part filter not exists { ?s <.doesService> ?part }  }  }` - note I introduces a class `:Shop` in the beginning to return only shops, if you don;t have such a class, just use the `doesService` property with a random object instead, e.g. `?s <.doesService> ?o .`

Comment: Sorry, that did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Just make it simple by returning only the shop that does service for car engine.

```
SELECT ?sh WHERE {
   ?sh rdf:type Shop.
   ?e rdf:type Engine.
   ?sh doesService ?e .
}
```